# books on curves

Tags: differential-geometry, book-recommendation, curves

I've read a few introductory texts on differential geometry, focusing on my specific interest in plane and space curves in Euclidean space. The breadth of coverage seems more or less the same (Frenet, Hopf, Fary-Milnor, four-vertex, isoperimetric, etc.). I have an impression that some advanced or more contemporary aspects of curves are missing. For example, aberrancy I have not seen discussed in book form so far, as a topic in curve theory.

Can anyone suggest any more intermediate/advanced DG text with greater coverage on curves?

Comment: I do not believe there has been a (recent) book that discusses the aberrancy of a curve; the papers I linked to in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/39034) would still be the most accessible references. Other than that, perhaps you can look at [Zwikker](https://books.google.com/books?id=5udUAAAAYAAJ) and see if it suits you?